# How to insert into a table with not null columns using json?

Tags: json, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.6, node-postgres

I am trying to insert into a table `food` with multiple not-null default columns, with commands like:

- `food_insertone('{"id": 1, "taste": "sweet"}'::JSON)`
- `food_insertone('{"id": 2}'::JSON)`
- `food_insertone('{"id": 3, "taste": null}'::JSON)`

And the result should be like:

```
INSERTED 1, 'sweet'
INSERTED 2, ''
ERROR (null not allowed in taste)
```

The table `food` is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE "food" (
  "id"    INT,
  "taste" TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  ...
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "food_insertone" (JSON)
RETURNS VOID AS $$
  INSERT INTO "food" SELECT * FROM json_populate_record(NULL::"food", $1);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

And i am trying to insert as:

```
SELECT food_insertone('{"id": 1}'::JSON);
```

But this doesnt work and gives me an error:

```
null value in column "taste" violates not-null constraint
```

I understand that `json_populate_record()` creates NULL values for columns which are not mentioned in the JSON, which is causing NULL to be inserted, and thus this error. A plain insert would work, but this is a dynamic table.

Comment: please show the insert statement

Comment: With plain insert, i meant something like `INSERT INTO "food" (id) VALUES (1)` for this particular case, but table has multiple such column.

Comment: I just want to use default value if it is not specified in the json, but still not allow null.

Comment: Would it be possible to concat the row values from `json_populate_record()` with a row of default values of the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to use the default value simple case:

```
t=# create table food(id int, t text not null default 'some');
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into food(id) SELECT id FROM json_populate_record(NULL::"food", '{"id":0}');
INSERT 0 1
t=# select * from food ;
 id |  t
----+------
  0 | some
(1 row)
```

using coalesce and another value:

```
t=# insert into food(id,t) 
SELECT id,coalesce(t,'some simple other value') 
FROM json_populate_record(NULL::"food", '{"id":0}');
```

and of course you can use some monstrous way to get actual default value in :

```
t=# insert into food(id,t) SELECT id,coalesce(t,rtrim) FROM json_populate_record(NULL::"food", '{"id":0}') join (select rtrim(ltrim(split_part(column_default,'::',1),$$'$$),$$'$$) from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'food' and column_name = 't') dflt on true;
INSERT 0 1
t=# select * from food ;
 id |            t
----+-------------------------
  0 | some simple other value
  0 | some
(2 rows)
```

Comment: But i also want to insert the value of `t` if its provided (as long as it is not null).

Comment: i think your monstrous way is the best because i dont know either the columns or thier default values before hand (i am using `alter` to add columns). but i couldnt understand what it does, could you explain?

Comment: i think a got another monstrous method: 1. to get default values as json (`SELECT json_object_agg(column_name, column_default)::JSONB FROM information_schema.columns WHERE (table_schema, table_name) = ('public', 'food');`).

Comment: 2. i could then append this to the original input json and do json_populate_record(), that should work. thanks.

Comment: i think you put some extra $ which is not part of the command. i see it was needed to remove the type cast. i am using this query now and it works: `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "table_default" (TEXT)
RETURNS JSON AS $$
  SELECT json_object_agg(column_name, replace(split_part(column_default,'::',1), E'\'', ''))
  FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE (table_schema, table_name) = ('public', $1);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STRICT IMMUTABLE;
`.

Comment: your function does not operate column names and your replace of `'` with nothing will fail if you have default value `I'm blue` - this is why I ltrim and rtrim instead

Comment: yes ltrim rtim quotes is a better idea, this worked for me because i didnt have any such default text you mentioned. i didnt understand what you meant by operate column names.